# View.OnLongClick() doesn't work when implementing onTouch() ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, touch-event

I'm trying to enable drag and dropping imageviews after the imageview has been held for a certain duration (long click).

So the dragging and dropping works fine (onTouch `ACTION_DOWN`/`ACTION_MOVE`/`ACTION_UP`), however it prevents me from detecting `View.OnLongClick`. When I remove the `onTouch`, the `OnLongClick` is successfully detected.

How can I get these 2 listeners to be working side by side?

onCreate:

```
{
    editPhoto1.setOnTouchListener(this)
    editPhoto2.setOnTouchListener(this)
    editPhoto3.setOnTouchListener(this)
    editPhoto1.isLongClickable = true
    editPhoto2.isLongClickable = true
    editPhoto3.isLongClickable = true
    editPhoto1.setOnLongClickListener(this)
    editPhoto2.setOnLongClickListener(this)
    editPhoto3.setOnLongClickListener(this)
}
```

onLongClick

```
override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG, "LongClick") // doesn't fire
    when (v){
        is CircleImageView -> {
            v.elevation = 20f
            v.borderColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)
            ready = true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

onTouch

```
override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

    if (v is CircleImageView){
        when (event?.action){
            ACTION_DOWN -> {
                v.alpha = 0.7f
            }
            ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (!ready) return false

                ...
            }
    return true
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Because the event is already being consumed by onTouch .Theoratically,
If you can return false from touch(not consumed for long click), it should work

Comment: Yep simply changing `return true` to `return false` in `onTouch()` worked - thankyou!

Comment: Just to confirm: only 1 listener can be executed on a view each time?

Comment: yes .. only ontouch would work if you consume the event